# Why my NSSplitViewItem hides its subviews before collapse is done

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, nssplitview

I'm trying to setup a simple and common layout in Interface Builder: a splitview with a side bar (left) and a content view, which itself holds a splitview with a content view (left) and a sidebar (right). Both side bars should collapse when reaching a given minimum width (100px).

The holding priorities are:

- main splitview: 245 and 240 (left side bar and content view, respectively)
- embedded splitview: 240 and 249 (content view and right side bar, respectively)

While the left bar behaves as expected (collapsing and uncollapsing back), the one on the right hides its content view before releasing the mouse button from the splitter, leading to an unrecoverable side bar.

This behaviour is shown on the gif below:

[3 panes NSSplitView glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lphrR.gif)

Does anyone has experienced (and fixed) such a behaviour ?
I'm using Xcode 12.3 on macOS 10.15.7

Comment: Have you deliberately nested two splitviews or are you trying to simulate a 3 pane splitview? What are the horizontal constraints in the panes?

Comment: The basic idea was to get something close to the Xcode interface. I first tried with 3 `NSSplitViewItem` objects in a single `NSSplitViewController`, which produced the same result. Then I switched to this version with nested `NSSplitViewControllers`, on which this post is based.

Comment: And there is no particular constraint for the panes, except the `minimalThickness` property, set to 100px

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. The pane uncollapses when it has the same width as the middle pane. The left pane has the same issue.